# What is the proper way to use factories/services in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have basic factory that looks like this:

```
mModule.factory('ajax_post', ['$http',  function(_http) {   
return{
    init: function(jsonData){
        var _promise= _http.post('src/php/data.ajax.php',
            jsonData
            ,{
                headers: {
                    'SOAPActions': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems'
                }
            }
            );            
        return _promise; 
    }
}]);
```

And here I call it in my controller:

```
 ajax_post.init($scope.jsonData)
    .then(function (result) {
        if(result.status == 200){
            $scope.isDone = true;
            ....              
        }                 
    }, 
    function (error) {
        alert(error.message);               
    });
```

I want to use `$scope` for other purposes here, but it seems like I can use only the parent (aka `$rootScope`). I only have one controller.

So here are some questions:

1. Is it good practice to use `$scope` in a factory/service, or should only the controller must use it (because according to MVC, I know `$scope` represents `View` for current `Model`).
2. Can I ignore `return` in factory/services, or should they **must** return something?
3. Can I implement `promise.then(..)` into a factory/service (meaning: can I put my above call from the controller into a factory/service)?  Or is the only right way to create promises and call them from controllers?
4. Why should I not implement the aforementioned `service` logic in the `controller` body?
5. Can I write several methods that call each another in one service?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it good practice to use $scope in a factory/service, or should only the controller must use it (because according to MVC, I know $scope represents View for current Model).

Avoiding modifying the $scope and only doing one thing is imho better for reusability.

> Can I ignore return in factory/services, or should they must return something?

You must return the object you're gonna use, like you do here.

> Can I implement promise.then(..) into a factory/service (meaning: can I put my above call from the controller into a factory/service)? Or is the only right way to create promises and call them from controllers?

You *can* pass your scope in your `.init` code, but then you're coupling your directive with your controller

> Why should I not implement the aforementioned service logic in the controller body?

The controller should not know how to query microsoft DB. The controller's role is to "prepare data", not to obtain them.

> Can I write several methods that call each another in one service?

Which would do?

Comment: Then yes, you can, but you may want to call the service from the controller

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen you want to use the q library. Like this:

```
app.factory('Data', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        ajaxItems: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({ method: "GET", url: "/Home/GetSearchResults" })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject(data);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});

app.controller('ResultsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Data', function ($scope, Data) {
    $scope.get = function () {
        $scope.items = Data.ajaxItems();
        // q returns a promise and THEN items
        $scope.items.then(function (items) {
            $scope.items = items;
        }, function (status) {
            console.log(status);
        });
    };
}]);
```